# fstab mount nested folders in order

Tags: arch-linux, mount, fstab, automounting

I have a partition mounted to `/home` and want to mount another partition as `$HOME/Steam`. The /home partition is encrypted and only mounted at login (not by fstab btw), while the Steam partition is not and fstab will mount it directly at boot. When I log in, the home partition will be mounted over it and hide its content. It will appear to be empty.

How do I tell fstab to wait for the other partition?

Comment: This might be helpful: https://askubuntu.com/a/48964

Comment: I already found this, but to my knowledge rc.local is not used anymore because of systemd.

Comment: Err, I didn't mean to suggest that as a solution, but as a root cause of the problem.  You can take a look here for something related to rc.local and systemd: https://askubuntu.com/a/919598

Comment: @AndyDalton I think I found the root cause is the encryption of my home drive.

Comment: Don't use `fstab`, use [`.mount` units](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.mount.html). That should also take care of your dependency problem because _"If a mount unit is beneath another mount unit in the file system hierarchy, both a requirement dependency and an ordering dependency between both units are created automatically."_

Comment: @don_crissti So I need to set `x-systemd.requires=` so that it will wait for the user to login. What should I put there?

Comment: Something like `home-yourusername.mount`... or [whatever that mount unit name is...](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/345518/22142)

Comment: [Don't write mount units, use fstab as the systemd docs recommend you](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90723/is-there-any-reason-to-move-away-from-fstab-on-a-systemd-system/427286#427286).

Comment: @sourcejedi If I used `x-systemd.requires=` in my fstab, wouldn't this generate a mount unit? Is there a target that is only called after login? Alternatively, which target does pam have?

Comment: read the link? fstab generates mount units always.  No.  None.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, sorry.

The encrypted filesystem is mounted by something like pam_mount or pam_ecryptfs.  This happens after the boot process.  This mount unit won't be part of the boot "transaction", and therefore ordering dependencies on it will have no effect on boot.

The best you can do is mount the partition, and then create a *symbolic link* file.  (`ln -s $HOME/Steam /mnt/Steam`).

If you want the Steam filesystem to be more private, make the real mount point something like `/mnt/$USER/Steam`, and set permissions on `/mnt/$USER` using `chmod o-rwx`.

Comment: Steam doesn't even recognize symbolic links a folders

Comment: @piegames in that case Steam must have code which deliberately checks for them :).  Steam really ought to let you set `/mnt/Steam` directly in that case.

Comment: For people stumbling on this, https://askubuntu.com/a/774499/68690 may be of interest