# How to force OS reload of fstab?

Tags: fstab

`mount -a` works fine as a one-time action.  But auto-mount of removable media reverts to settings that were in fstab at the last reboot.

How to make the OS reload `/etc/fstab` so auto-mounts use the new settings when media is connected?

The specific example seen with Raspbian (Debian) Stretch:

- FAT-formatted SD card; configured fstab to auto-mount; rebooted; volume auto-mounts, but read-only.
- Changed `umask` options in `/etc/fstab`; `mount -a` while media is connected, and volume is now read-write.
- Unmount and re-insert the media; auto-mount works, but using the options in `/etc/fstab` from the last reboot, so volume is read-only.
- Reboot; OS loads updated `/etc/fstab`; auto-mount works when media is connected, and volume is read-write.  How to get this effect without a reboot?

FWIW, the (updated) `/etc/fstab` syntax was:

```
/dev/sdb1   /Volumes/boot   vfat    rw,user,exec,nofail,umask=0000  0   0
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I suspect this is caused by systemd’s conversion of `/etc/fstab`; traditional `mount` doesn’t remember the contents of `/etc/fstab`.

To refresh systemd’s view of the world, including changes to `/etc/fstab`, [run](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#daemon-reload)

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

Comment: Sigh. An auto-generated comment in the top of `/etc/fstab` reminding/advising people it has now been deprecated - and how to update `systemd` - would go a long way.

Comment: Thanks!  You can imagine Google returned nothing but 'mount -a' hits for this query.  Are there any unwanted side-effects when doing this on-the-fly re-gen of the tables?  Doesn't seem to be.

Comment: For more, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/236968/5132 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90723/ .  Note that the Debian service that used to run `mount -a` is nowadays masked.

Answer (score 24):

To elaborate the [answer from *@Stephen Kitt*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/477811/243074): for example I have this entry in `/etc/fstab`:

```
vnetsvr-home:/etc/skel   /etc/skel    nfs4   sec=krb5p,noauto,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.idle-timeout=10min   0   0
```

and only doing `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` doesn't reloaded the fstab. I have to do:

```bash
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart remote-fs.target
```

To reload an entry to mount a local filesystem, you should use:

```bash
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart local-fs.target
```

Comment: This answer worked for me in regards to Ubuntu 16.04 while the accepted answer did not.

Comment: Even this answer does not help me when removing entries from `/etc/fstab`. So, I opt for the reboot.

Comment: If you're using "noauto" option, this answer resolves the issue.

Comment: This answer worked for me in RedHat 8, however, the accepted answer did not.

Comment: This answer worked for me in Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

I know that these solutions might not work in every linux distro and version.
However this method would generally works for all Linux versions.
1- Do your configuration and change the fstab file
2- Use this command to remount the device_file you have changed its configuration in the fstab file:
`# mount -o remount [device_file]`
This way you will mount the partition with its new configuration read from "fstab" file.
If you removed a partition from "fstab" file, simply `umount [device_file]`. Be sure, the partition stays unmounted after the reboot.

Any time you can check the result by running `mount` command.